# I'm trying to use auto increment in MySql and it should start with a particular number

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

```
create table foo(
id  int(12)  primary key AUTO_INCREMENT=100,
name char(20)
);
```

it states that you have an incorrect syntax

Comment: `int(12)` makes zero sense, you will not get a number with 12 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

or instead of `1`, pass whatever value from which you want to start.